# In LibreOffice Calc, is it possible to use a complex function and a data range as arguments for a MIN() function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I'm going to simplify *a bit* to hopefully get at the crux of my question.

I have a spreadsheet in which a cell has a massive formula. (Again, I'm simplifying to avoid a question that is so long no one will read it).

At the last minute, a new variable was introduced.  If this new variable is less than the value of that formula, the formula should return this new variable instead.

This is a perfect use of the MIN() function, but I'm having challenges getting the MIN() function to use a complex formula (which has many IF statements in it) as one of its arguments and a data range as another.

For example, this did not work:

> MIN(NEW_DATA_RANGE,IF(x=y/pi...))

Where `NEW_DATA_RANGE` is a data range containing the new variable.

If I replace `NEW_DATA_RANGE` with a literal constant, it works fine.  Similarly, if I replace the formula with a literal constant, it works fine.  But when I try to take the MIN() of a value in the data range *and* a complex formula, LibreOffice always returns zero (0).

Is this likely a bug in LibreOffice Calc, or is there some reason you can't use a data range and complex formula as arguments for the MIN() function?

Comment: min() expects a range or a list of values. What happens when you replace the range by a function returning the value of that range, eg. another min() ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's a clever idea.  I'm trying it now, and will report back.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille You're on to something! MIN() within a MIN() causes the same problem, and MAX() within a MIN() generates incorrect results, but ABS() works!  So now I just need to find a workaround function that will not change the values of the variables in the data range.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille You're a rock star! This works: `MIN((NEW_DATA_RANGE+0),IF(x=y/pi...))`  !!!  Thank you so very much for leading the path to a solution!  If you would like to write up an answer, I'll accept it.  If not, I'll write up a little something after a day or two.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Well, it wound up be a touch more complicated, and I don't love my solution, but it works.  Within the data range, the variable may exist, or may not.  Adding 0 to the minimum caused it to always exist, and so often MIN() returned 0.  My solution is: `MIN(IF(NEW_DATA_RANGE,NEW_DATA_RANGE,99999),IF(x=y/pi...)))`.  The largest possible resultant is 99999, so this covers all cases.  If you think of something more elegant, I'm all eyes. ;)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Actually, LibreOffice Calc wouldn't quite work with that.  I needed to employ the '+0' trick again to make it work: `MIN(IF(NEW_DATA_RANGE,NEW_DATA_RANGE+0,99999),IF(x=y/pi...)))`

Comment: To be clear: NEW_DATA_RANGE was a single cell or multiple cells?  "this did not work":  did you get a syntax error?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thank you for all your help and your answer.  NEW_DATA_RANGE is a range consisting of a single column. By "this did not work" (in the original question), I meant that the value returned was zero (0) whenever the corresponding cell in NEW_DATA_RANGE was greater than zero, but less than the formula result.

Comment: That does smell buggy.  When I tried to combine a named range with a simple value, I got Error:509.  LibreOffice 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation isn't very specific about this, MIN() expects either a range of cells, or a list of values as parameters.  As your function returns a value, the other parameters for MIN() also have to be values.  So you need to pass NEW_DATA_RANGE as a parameter to another function returning a value.  Eg.

```
=MIN(MIN(NEW_DATA_RANGE),IF(x=y/pi...))
```

If NEW_DATA_RANGE can contain an empty cell

```
=IF(ISEMPTY(A),IF(x=y/pi...),MIN(MIN(A),IF(x=y/pi...)))
```

I would replace the IF(...) by a user-defined function.